# Mysql select one of duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the latest entry of the duplicate entries against the ticket_id in a mysql table , My current is something like this.

```
SELECT  * ,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt ,
        ticket_id
FROM    temp_tickets
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

It gives the number of times a row is duplicated but i am able to select the latest one of those mulptiple rows

Let say i have 3 ticket_id's which got duplicated for 5 times so now i want to select the latest occurrence from all these 3 id's .

Lemme know if i have to be more specific.

Thanks

Comment: And you still need the `COUNT` as well in the same query? Or you just want a result set for the latest entry in each set of duplicates?

Comment: @martin latest of all dulpicate sets

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way (assuming "latest" means "greatest id")

```
SELECT  temp_tickets.*
FROM    temp_tickets
        JOIN ( SELECT   MAX(id) AS id
               FROM     temp_tickets
               GROUP BY ticket_id
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
             ) latest ON latest.id = temp_tickets.id
```

I suspect it might be possible to come up with a more efficient solution [involving user variables](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) but I'll leave that to someone else...